# Golang Gin Base HTML Template

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a base html template and want to work it with in all html files.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    // Şablon dosyalarını yükleme
    r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*.html")

    r.GET("/page1", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(200, "base.html", gin.H{
            "title":   "Page 1 IS HERE",
            "content": "page1.html",
        })
    })

    r.GET("/page2", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(200, "base.html", gin.H{
            "title":   "Page 2 IS HERE",
            "content": "page2.html",
        })
    })

    r.Run("127.0.0.1:8080")
}
```

my base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{.title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>BASELINE</h1>
    <div id="content">
        {{template "content" .}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

page1.html

```
{{define "content"}}
<h2>Welcome to Page 1</h2>
<p>This is the content of Page 1.</p>
{{end}}
```

page2.html

```
{{define "content"}}
<h2>Welcome to Page 2</h2>
<p>This is the content of Page 2.</p>
{{end}}
```

Print;
**/page1** = Welcome to **Page 2**
This is the content of Page 2.

**/page**2 = Welcome to **Page 2**
This is the content of Page 2.

When I run this code, both link use page2.html content. How can I fix it?

Comment: You cannot define the same template names `content`, they will be overwritten.

Comment: so is there any way to do this? I need to make a html template

Comment: You could try it with https://github.com/foolin/goview. See the `gin` examples at here https://github.com/foolin/goview/tree/master/_examples/

Comment: Just use different names for the definitions and use a variable in the `template` action (you already have one named content that is currently unused).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve what you need by using the HTML templates in the following way. First, let me present my project structure:

- appName

  - templates

    - footer.tmpl
    - header.tmpl
    - page1.tmpl
    - page2.tmpl
  - main.go

Now, let's start with templates definition.

#### Templates definition

##### `header.tmpl` file

```
{{define "header.tmpl" }}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{.title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>BASELINE</h1>
    <div id="content">
{{end}}
```

##### `footer.tmpl` file

```
{{define "footer.tmpl"}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

##### `page1.tmpl` file

```
{{template "header.tmpl"}}
<h2>Welcome to Page 1</h2>
<p>This is the content of Page 1.</p>
{{template "footer.tmpl"}}
```

##### `page2.tmpl` file

```
{{template "header.tmpl"}}
<h2>Welcome to Page 2</h2>
<p>This is the content of Page 2.</p>
{{template "footer.tmpl"}}
```

#### The `main.go` file

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    gin.SetMode(gin.DebugMode)
    r := gin.Default()

    // load templates
    r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*.tmpl")

    r.GET("/page1", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(200, "page1.tmpl", gin.H{
            "title": "Page 1 IS HERE",
        })
    })

    r.GET("/page2", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(200, "page2.tmpl", gin.H{
            "title": "Page 2 IS HERE",
        })
    })

    r.Run("127.0.0.1:8080")
}
```

First, we added the invocation to  `gin.SetMode(gin.DebugMode)`. Thanks to this, we're able to see which templates are actually loaded in our `gin.Renderer` instance.
By using the method `LoadHTMLGlob` we load all of them. The pattern matches any `*.tmpl` file we define on the file system.
The remaining code is more or less the same as you wrote within the question.
By using this method you should be able to avoid the duplication of the common structure by using two `tmpl` files.
Probably, there is an even more elegant way of achieving this. In case someone finds it, just let me know, thanks!

Comment: FYI, `golang/pkgsite` implements it differently. First, it [creates a map of templates](https://github.com/golang/pkgsite/blob/96436fe69a2cad14c2c0d94a0d5fcdac5d686791/internal/frontend/server.go#L739-L789). Then when a page is requested, it [uses a corresponding template to  render the page](https://github.com/golang/pkgsite/blob/96436fe69a2cad14c2c0d94a0d5fcdac5d686791/internal/frontend/server.go#L678-L687).